# Spnego Authentication with JAAS Login - JBOSS Negotiation

Tags: spnego

Tried integrating jboss negotiation in application. Done below changes in the related files :

> 1. Added jboss-negotiation-2.0.3.GA.jar  in  {jboss-home}/{configuration}/lib
> 2. Added highlighted attributes in {jboss-home}/{configuration}/deploy/properties-service.xml

```
 <mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" name="jboss:type=Service,name=SystemProperties">
                 <attribute name="Properties">
                 java.security.krb5.kdc=corp.ABC.com
                 java.security.krb5.realm=CORP.ABC.COM
                 </attribute>
```

> 3. Added below entry in {Jobb-home}/server/abc/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/META-INF/ war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml

```
           <entry>
             <key>SPNEGO</key>
             <value>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator</value></entry>
```

> 4. Added below entry in login-conf.xml

```
   <application-policy name="host">
   <authentication>
          <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required">
                 <module-option name="storeKey">true</module-option>
                 <module-option name="useKeyTab">true</module-option>
                 <module-option name="principal">ABCDEF@ABC.XYZ.COM</moduleoption>
                 <module-option name="keyTab">ABC.keytab</module-option>
                 <module-option name="doNotPrompt">true</module-option>
                 <module-option name="debug">true</module-option>
          </login-module>
   </authentication>
   </application-policy>


   <application-policy name="SPNEGO">
   <authentication>
   <login-module code="org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule" flag="requisite">
          <module-option name="password-stacking">useFirstPass</module-option>
          <module-option name="serverSecurityDomain">host</module-option>
   </login-module>
   <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
          <module-option name="password-stacking">useFirstPass</module-option>
           <module-option name="usersProperties">spnego_Users.properties</module-option>
           <module-option name="rolesProperties">spengo_roles.properties</module-option>
   </login-module>
   </authentication>
```

> 5. Added below in web.xml

```
<login-config>
                    <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
                    <realm-name>SPNEGO</realm-name>
        </login-config>
```

Need to allow basic authentication for users who access the application via internet and Spnego for Active directory users. Found below error

2015-06-10 08:54:36,684 TRACE [org.jboss.security.plugins.auth.JaasSecurityManagerBase.SPNEGO] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-12) Login failure
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.security.negotiation.spnego.SPNEGOLoginModule.login(SPNEGOLoginModule.java:117)